# Как интегрировать несколько аккаунтов фейсбук с телеграмм? (ввести переписку через 1 TG с друзьями на неск. FB аках)

Tags: node.js, electron

Есть модуль https://github.com/Schmavery/facebook-chat-api,
есть хороший пример его использования:

```
const login = require("facebook-chat-api");

// Create simple echo bot
login({email: "FB_EMAIL", password: "FB_PASSWORD"}, (err, api) => {
    if(err) return console.error(err);

    api.listen((err, message) => {
        api.sendMessage(message.body, message.threadID);
    });
});
```

Нужно просто запустить этот код для двух FB_EMAIL;FB_PASSWORD на Electron.

Есть документация: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/multithreading, но нет знания английского и почти нет опыта работы с js, node.js, electron что бы понять поможет/не поможет (в документации есть какие-то оговорки). Изучать?

Answer (score 0):

Читать https://medium.com/devschacht/node-hero-chapter-3-cae7333c7f3d
Похоже, что многопоток в js/node.js/electron исключительно для использования всех ядер процессора может быть нужен. Получается, что для всего остального есть асинхронность.